# Convert Docker Compose to a service create command

Tags: docker, service, docker-compose

As said in the title, I want to create a commando from a YML file.
Unfortunately, I am unable to finde some parts, e.g. Depend_on.

I already have:

```
samle_1:
  image: image:0.1.0
  environment:
    - SQL_PROVIDER_NAME=mariadb
    - NOSQL_PROVIDER_NAME=mongodb
  networks:
    - back-tier
    - front-tier
  expose:
    - "10180"
  ports:
    - "10188:10188"
    - "10189:10189"
  depends_on:
    - samle_2
    - samle_3
```

Which I converted as follows:

```
docker service create --name samle_1 \
--hostname samle_1 \
--replicas=1 \
--network back-tier \
--network front-tier \
--env SQL_PROVIDER_NAME=mariadb \
--env NOSQL_PROVIDER_NAME=mongodb \
--publish 10180 \
image:0.1.0
```

Now I do not know how to handle ports, expose and depend_on.
I read already the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/), but cant find any answer